# Regarding Threejs texture Animation

Tags: three.js

I'm Working with `Threejs` in which I'm Facing Problems with Textures, so I would like to ask A question that is, how to load the textures without starting the animation, it shows blank image without starting the animation. Can anyone tell me how to do that..

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 15, 5.3, 2 );
var te = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("b4.jpg") ;
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: "",map:te} );
plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
plane.position.set(-12.89,-7.2,19);
plane.visible=false;
scene.add( plane );
```

Comment: Please add some code to your question illustrating how you currently setup animated textures.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try having a callback function to trigger after the texture is successfully loaded? Like how it is done in the documentation: [TextureLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader)

So something like:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 15, 5.3, 2 );

var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
// load a resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'b4.jpg',
    // Function when resource is loaded
    function ( texture ) {
        // do something with the texture
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: "",map:te} );
        plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);

        plane.position.set(-12.89,-7.2,19);

        plane.visible=false;

        scene.add( plane );
    },
    // Function called when download errors
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( 'An error happened' );
    }
);
```